# How to check if an array contains element that can be found in another array and store their values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the two objects below have matching elements?
If they have matching elements ..I would like to store the matching elements in an empty variable called `var storeHere = []`.

```
var one = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-24", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-22", "2021-02-21", "2021-03-02", "2021-02-11", "2021-02-10"];
var two = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-25", "2021-02-23"];

var storeHere = [];
```

So far I managed to match the two objects and get either a true or a false if there is a match but i would also like to store the matching values in an emtpy variable.

```
var one = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-24", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-22", "2021-02-21", "2021-03-02", "2021-02-11", "2021-02-10"];
var two = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-25", "2021-02-23"];

function ex (alldates, selected) {
    return selected.some(function (v) {
        return alldates.indexOf(v) >= 0;
    });
};
    ex(one, two);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options

You can use `Array.filter`:

```js
const one = [
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-24",
    "2021-02-23",
    "2021-02-22",
    "2021-02-21",
    "2021-03-02",
    "2021-02-11",
    "2021-02-10",
];

const two = [
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-23",
];

// If an element is in two, include it. Otherwise, exclude it.
const storeHere = one.filter((date) => two.includes(date))

console.log(storeHere) // [ '2021-02-25', '2021-02-23' ]
```

Or you can use ES6 sets with `Set.has`:

```js
const one = [
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-24",
    "2021-02-23",
    "2021-02-22",
    "2021-02-21",
    "2021-03-02",
    "2021-02-11",
    "2021-02-10",
];

const two = new Set([
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-25",
    "2021-02-23",
]);

// If an element is in two, include it. Otherwise, exclude it.
const storeHere = one.filter((date) => two.has(date))

console.log(storeHere) // [ '2021-02-25', '2021-02-23' ]
```

The advantage of the set is that it's faster, because it only contains unique elements (if any repeated elements exist). However, the difference is probably minor, since both solutions are basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var one = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-24", "2021-02-23", "2021-02-22", "2021-02-21", "2021-03-02", "2021-02-11", "2021-02-10"];
var two = ["2021-02-25", "2021-02-25", "2021-02-23"]; 
var storeHere = [];


one.forEach(date => {
   if(two.includes(date)) {
       storeHere.push(date);
   }
}
```